# echo php variable in backbone.js template

Tags: javascript, php, session, backbone.js

I m trying to access my session variable in backbone template which render with underscore.js

```
template : _.template(template)
```

i am working on login module .
after login i set session in backend with php , which is working fine. session is started.

on success is set username with js, but it get vanish if someone refreshed the page so in case of refresh i bring up session variable.

Now i want to show session data in my template like

```
<li><a href="#" id="loginUser"><?php isset($_SESSION['username'])? echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a></li>
```

but i am not getting those value ?

any help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Sessions do store the **session_id in the cookie**, (depending on the configuration, but default is:) **nothing else**.

E.g. setting `$_SESSION['username']` does not send a cookie called `username`.

You cannot access these variables, they are stored in files on the server in /tmp directories,
on my server it's

```
session.save_path => /var/lib/php5 => /var/lib/php5
```

And the option to save session in files is

```
session.save_handler => files => files
```

These variables can be obtained through `php -i | grep session` or `phpinfo();`.

You have to explicitly set a cookie using [`set_cookie();`](https://www.php.net/set_cookie) to make it accessable through JavaScript.